# OS X prefers case insensitivity but TimeMachine seems to require case sensitivity?

Tags: time-machine

As per [What are the downsides to using Time Machine?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24667/what-are-the-downsides-to-using-time-machine/24695#24695) the first item reads *Time machine requires an Apple specific HFS+ filesystem to store backups.* Which is a `Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)` disk. But then, OS X of course wants `Mac OS Extended (Journaled)`. Just like most everyone else I get:

*This volume has the wrong case sensitivity for a backup.*

After hours of googling, I've not read that there is absolutely no workaround.

Comment: Why don't you format your Time Machine target case-insensitive?

Comment: @patrix The immediate problem is that I need to rollback to yesterday. I botched the Soundflower install. If I can't use TM, I suspect it will take a lot of care / effort to remove Soundflower. Once I get this Soundflower problem resolved, I'm definitely going to reformat TM to case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked answer doesn't say that Time Machine requires *...Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)...*. It only says *Time machine requires an Apple specific HFS+ filesystem to store backups* and it should be read as *the Apple specific HFS+ filesystem*.

With other words: Time Machine can't backup data directly to NTFS/FAT32 or EXT3/4 volumes.

Comment: I set-up TM years ago, and I knew Macs did not like case-sensitivity. I can't believe I chose case-sensitive. I thought maybe TM has some roll in formatting, and maybe that's what happened. If I can get my roll-back to yesterday to uninstall Soundflower, I'll delete 4 years of TM and start anew on a case-insensitive disk.

Comment: There's no uninstall script. The only Soundflower file in my filesystem was the *.dmg file (which I deleted). Still, Soundflower shows-up in Audio MIDI Setup. I re-boot. Still in Audio MIDI Setup. I'm not well versed enough at OSX to really drill down and figure-out how audio works. I'm not sure and don't want to risk breaking something. I tried controlling the volume of 2 Bluetooth speakers with Soundflower. Didn't work. So, not the end of the world.

Comment: yep. Uninstall.scrpt did the job! I need to learn more about GitHub... I think I had trouble with Soundflower because I'm using El Capitan.  I'm going to give Soundflower another shot sometime.

Comment: @david The question above is about Time Machine. If you have issues with the uninstallation of Soundflower, please ask a new question for this instead of discussing it in the comments.

Comment: @patrix I just want to acknowledge I'm no longer investing my time on this, so I don't want anyone else to either. I'm reformatting and making today "day zero" of my TimeMachine. That should do it.

Comment: Invest the same amount of time to Soundflower… forget it & move on. Not worth the effort since Mavericks. Feel free to ask 'sound-related' further questions in Ask Different, though consumer-level workarounds for audio routing come down to one app, [Audio Hijack](http://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) which is expensive for a one-trick pony, but very good at what it does. [speaking as a sound engineer, rather than a Mac user]